# Virtualenv.py has no main attirute

Tags: python-2.7, virtualenv

I'm having trouble with my initial virtualenv setup on Mac OS 10.8.5.

After using pip to install, I have the following error when I try to run virtualenv:

```
ObLaDalocal:~ dbunz$ virtualenv 
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 8, in <module>
        load_entry_point('virtualenv==1.11.4', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 318, in load_entry_point
        return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2221, in load_entry_point
        return ep.load()
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 1959, in load
        raise ImportError("%r has no %r attribute" % (entry,attr))
    ImportError: <module 'virtualenv' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/py2app/recipes/virtualenv.py'> has no 'main' attribute

ObLaDalocal:~ dbunz$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/py2app/recipes/
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to burn some things to the ground, but I was able to get virtualenv to run properly.

1. Set up pip for multi-version mode: (sudo easy_install -m pip)
2. Uninstall virtualenv: sudo pip uninstall virtualenv
3. Reinstall virtualenv sudo pip install virtualenv

Not particularly magical.